# onEdit function edits all the items aside from the one its being called on

Tags: javascript, html, class, oop

Im working on a todo list app and was developing the onEdit method and I encountered a problem, the method works just fine when its called once but after calling it for the second time on another todo/object,it changes the value of all the other items in my local storage to the same thing,however the problem is fixed by adding location.reload() to the method itself but Im sure there is another way to fix this issue

this is the method that calls in updateTodo() from the Storage component

```
confirmEdit(id){
const todo = {
  title : editTodoInput.value,
  id : id
 }
 Storage.updateTodo(todo)
 this.toggleEditTodoModal()
 this.setApp()
}
```

and this is the method itself

```
  static updateTodo(todo) {
  const savedTodos = this.getAllTodos();
  const editedTodo = savedTodos.find((t) => {
  return parseInt(t.id) == parseInt(todo.id);
  });
  editedTodo.title = todo.title;
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(savedTodos));
```

}

when I add location.reload() at the end of //updateTodo, everything works just fine.

Comment: Is this a React app? If so, then there is no reference to Reacts state logic here, so direct variable changes will not update the DOM.

Comment: no its just vanilla javascript, there are some other methods in the app that will update DOM objects once called

Comment: As it is vanilla JavaScript, I would submit your code as a executable snippet in the question so we can debug or provide all the relevant code.

Comment: @damonholden approved